# Authenticate users via LDAP using nginx

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, nginx, ldap, htaccess

I know how to auth the users via LDAP in apache2:

```
# put the following in the VirtualHost

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin user1@bar.foo.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please provide USERNAME AND PASSWORD"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ehh.foo.com/ou=ehh,o=foo.com?mail"
    Require valid-user
    Require ldap-attribute emailAddress=someuser@bar.foo.com
```

**Q:** But we need to use nginx. How can we configure nginx to auth via LDAP?

Using Ubuntu 12.04.5

Answer (score 8):

For this you need to download/clone, compile and install [nginx-auth-ldap](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap)

You can download the zip file:

```
wget https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
```

then `cd` to your **nginx** source folder and do:

```
./configure --add-module=~-/nginx-auth-ldap-master
sudo make install
```

After that you can configure `nginx`:

```
http {
  ldap_server test1 {
    url ldap://192.168.0.1:3268/DC=test,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person);
    binddn "TEST\\LDAPUSER";
    binddn_passwd LDAPPASSWORD;
    group_attribute uniquemember;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    require valid_user;
  }

  ldap_server test2 {
    url ldap://192.168.0.2:3268/DC=test,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person);
    binddn "TEST\\LDAPUSER";
    binddn_passwd LDAPPASSWORD;
    group_attribute uniquemember;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    require valid_user;
  }
}

server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;

    auth_ldap "Forbidden";
    auth_ldap_servers test1;
    auth_ldap_servers test2;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

As indicated in the modules documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [auth_pam](https://github.com/stogh/ngx_http_auth_pam_module/) module. It has for example been included in the last two stable Debian releases. It supports LDAP authentication (and a lot more) through PAM.

Comment: There's a pam module for nginx authentication?!

Comment: Not built-in, this looks like an open source add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I have written [nginx-auth-saslauthd](https://github.com/voegelas/nginx-auth-saslauthd), which interfaces nginx with the [saslauthd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/saslauthd) daemon and provides Basic authentication. The saslauthd daemon supports LDAP as well as PAM.